# MVC3 HOW TO PASS IN .load function of jquery the parameter include in url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How to pass in .load function of jquery, the parameter include in url.

url recived in create.cshtml => http://.../Invoiced/Create/1
InvoicedDetail is a partialView , this contain list of details by id, this id is the parameter in ulr http://.../Invoiced/Create/1, how to cathc this parameter "1" to send in .load function ?

thanks.

```
Create.cshtml

    <p>Details list</p>

    <div id="InvoicedDetails_content"><div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
    //         parameter  = ?;
                $('#InvoicedDetails_content').load('/InvoicedDetail/Index/' + parameter);
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: is ur question how to pass the parameter to the partial view or how to use the jquery load function .. be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never hardcode urls or any string concatenations. Always use urls helpers when you need to generate a url in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "InvoicedDetail", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] })';
    $('#InvoicedDetails_content').load(url);
});
</script>
```

In this example I am using the `id` parameter which assumes that you have this route parameter defined in your route definitions. Adapt the name if necessary.